When the MoveFile function fails in vb6, what error does it represent?
When using the MoveFile function in vb6, what error code does the function get if the function fails because the same file already exists in the path you want to navigate?
I don't know if there is an error code that occurs in a specific situation in order to try to handle an exception in a situation other than when you run the MoveFile function.
Is it possible that the error code that occurs when using the MoveFile function will have a different return value depending on the development platform?
if MoveINIFile(SrcPath, TargetPath) <> True Then
  Spread.SetText("Error")
else
  Spread.SetText("Upload")
end if

Using the MoveFile API function, a success message is displayed when the operation is successfully completed, and an error message is displayed when it fails.

There is no MoveFile function in VB6. If you are talking about the MoveFile Windows API, then see its documentation for the errors it returns. It does not have a development platform, it's Windows only. Then again, you are using MoveINIFile in your code, which is your custom function and not MoveFile.

If you are talking about MoveFile in FileSystemObject, then an error 58 is returned.
